# How to access a specific object attribute in Session Array?

Tags: javascript, session, meteor

If I have a Session in Meteor, declared like this:

```
Template.productsList.onCreated(function () {
    Session.setDefault('allProducts', [{
        productId: 1,
        quantity: 5,
        productName: "product 1",
        productDescription: "description",
        price: 19.99
    }, {
        productId: 2,
        quantity: 12,
        productName: "product 2",
        productDescription: "description",
        price: 9.99
    }, ]);
]);
```

I can get the array using: `Session.get('allProducts')`.

But, how can I access a specific value? Like 'quantity'?

Comment: `Session.get('allProducts')[0].quantity`

Comment: Quantity of a specific `product` or all the quantities?

Comment: Thanks Tushar, i could access one value.

AKS, how do i access all quantities ? For loop ?

Comment: @Chico You've to use `for` loop to get all values of quantity

Comment: Thank you all, really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of Session.get('allProducts') is just a array so every array property will work here.

Session.get('allProducts')[0].quantity will give you the 5.

Session.get('allProducts').map(function(a) {return a.quantity;}) will give you the array of quantity.

Comment: Thank you Pankaj, really appreciate the help